# How to properly call css folder outside of caller files?

Tags: php, html, css, file, path

I have this project structure:

**ProjectName** with a many child folders. One of it is **includes** folder which holds **static** folder that also holds **css** folder and **header.php**. Now my **header.php** calls my css files by doing this on my head tag:
`<link href="static/css/styles.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` and this header.php is called on one of my php file which is in another folder.

```
ProjectName
   includes
      static
         css
            styles.min.css
      header.php
   views
      employee
         departments.php
```

but when i run on my localhost. This is what i get: 
`GET http://localhost/TeamParrot/views/employee/static/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Below is the screen shot of what i am doing:

[image: Project Folder and deprtments.php]
Output
[image: Output]

Comment: Remove this `static/` try with `<link href="css/styles.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I already did that but still it cannot found.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani The entire problem is that relative includes aren't working, so that won't be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think that relative includes are the problem here. From the point you include the CSS, the file system thinks you're in `./TeamParrot/views/employee`.

Probably something on the lines of  :

```
<link href="/includes/static/css/styles.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

will work. The slash at the start of the include part instructs the CSS to load from the webroot.

Comment: I have solved it using this line ```<link href="../../includes/static/css/styles.min.css" rel="stylesheet">```. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @AnirudhLou Yeah! That will also work. Anything that gets the HTML looking in the right place for the CSS will work.